# Is it possible to create an "anonymous" initializer in C99?

Tags: c, initialization, c99

I'm using nested structs to create a sort of "struct inheritance" in plain C. For example, I have a few structs like this:

```
struct a {
    obj_type type_id;
    int x;
    int y;
}

struct b {
    struct a super;
    char* str;
}

struct c {
    struct a super;
    int* data;
    bool flag;
}
```

I then create an enum, like this:

```
typedef enum {
    OBJ_TYPE_A,
    OBJ_TYPE_B,
    OBJ_TYPE_C
} obj_type;
```

This lets me simulate inheritance by determining what struct various objects are by checking their `type_id`, then casting to the corresponding structs. My problem is that I want to be able to initialize these "child" structs without manually defining the `x` and `y` properties of the parent struct.

Basically, I *can* initialize a pointer like this:

```
struct b obj_b = { OBJ_TYPE_B, 0, 0, "foo" };
struct b *ptr_b = malloc(sizeof(struct b));
memcpy(ptr_b, &obj_b, sizeof(struct b));
```

However, I'd rather have a function to do the initialization of `a` for me, so I could do something like this:

```
struct b *ptr_b = object_create(OBJ_TYPE_B, { "foo" }, sizeof(struct b));
```

I've created something like an implementation of that function like this:

```
const struct a DEFAULT_A = { OBJ_TYPE_A, 0, 0 };

struct a object_create(obj_type type, void* data_ptr, size_t size) {
    struct a new_obj = malloc(size);
    memcpy(new_obj, &DEFAULT_A, sizeof(struct a));
    memcpy(new_obj + sizeof(struct a), data_ptr, size - sizeof(struct a));
    return new_obj;
}
```

However, I can't really use this because I have no way of doing something like this:

```
struct b *ptr_b = object_create(OBJ_TYPE_B, &{ "foo" }, sizeof(struct b));
```

Is there any way to create a sort of "anonymous" block of data to pass to a function? Or will I have to resort to something like macros to do the job?

Comment: Nope, but I think you you might be looking for C++11 initializer lists.

Comment: @Mehrdad, this is a C question not C++.

Comment: Besides the compound literals that H2CO3 showed you in his answer, you might also look into *designated initializers*, something like `{ .toto = 42 }`. Also you might better structure your initializers according to the nested structure of your `struct`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is indeed possible in C99. The above works for example, you just have to cast away the struct literal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct s {
    char *a;
};

void f(struct s *p)
{
    printf("%s\n", p->a);
}


int main()
{
    f(&(struct s){ "hello world" });
    return 0;
}
```

More on the topic in [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-compound-literals/184401404):

> Compound literals yield lvalues. This means that you can take the address of a compound literal, which is the address of the unnamed object declared by the compound literal. As long as the compound literal does not have a const-qualified type, you can use the pointer to modify it.

Comment: So, to confirm, I'd have to create an auxiliary struct which only contains the properties unique to my "child" struct, and cast to that?

Comment: @JakeKing Yes, something like that.